# Azure Data Factory Pagination Entry Format

Tags: azure, rest, pagination, azure-data-factory

I am working with Azure Data Factory V2 and a rest API.  I cannot figure out how to parse the next page link from the header and use it in the pagination.

This is the Response from Postman (in the Headers):

Link:

```
</well-rollups?action=prev&countyparish=TYLER+%5C%28TX%5C%29&deleteddate=null&pagesize=100&prev_page=before_beginning_of_recordset&state=TX>; rel="prev", </well-rollups?action=next&countyparish=TYLER+%5C%28TX%5C%29&deleteddate=null&next_page=api14+%3C+%2742457308280200%27&pagesize=100&state=TX>; rel="next"
```

There is also a 'Links' response:

Links:

```
</well-rollups?action=prev&countyparish=TYLER+%5C%28TX%5C%29&deleteddate=null&pagesize=100&prev_page=before_beginning_of_recordset&state=TX>; rel="prev", </well-rollups?action=next&countyparish=TYLER+%5C%28TX%5C%29&deleteddate=null&next_page=api14+%3C+%2742457308280200%27&pagesize=100&state=TX>; rel="next"
```

How do I format this for entry in `Name` and `Value`?

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be no difference between `Link` and `Links`.
As follows can this work ?
[image]

Comment: No, unfortunately it just keeps looping around on itself.  It doesn't seem to be parsing the link properly.